# Sending call over bluetooth from phone

Tags: bluetooth, audio-playback

I have paired my smartphone with Raspberry PI using bluez and blueman. But Now I want to pass the phonecall to the Pis audio system. I know that this too generic of a question here but what should I install? What do I need for this?
Basically, to be more explanatory, what I wish to do is to have full control of phone calls from Raspberry Pi. Basically, raspberry pi replacing a bluetooth headset or something similar. Answering phone calls, making phone calls transfer sound (my voice) from RPi to Phone Call and vice versa. Is there any ready package (or many) for this? If I have to implement it on my own, is there any protocol to implement? Can it be done in python?

Comment: Here is a great place to start: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68779

Answer (score 1):

To have full control on Raspberry pi you can use the ofono package
see this link.
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/network/ofono/ofono-1.15.tar.gz